# PFSense HAProxy DNS Rebind

Tags: haproxy, pfsense

I have installed PFSense and HAProxy Package behind Provider router with On Public IP,  when trying to redirect all HTTP/HTTPS traffic to ip assigned to PFSense,

I am getting HAProxy Front Ends getting invoked redirecting to https and then throwing DNS rebinding error. Suggestion/Recommendations please how to best solve this problem,